# Is there a way to use an enum for characters in a string? C++

Tags: c++, enums

This was taken off LeetCode but basically given a string composed of a few unique characters that each have an associated integer value, I need to quickly process the total integer value of the string. I thought enums would be useful since you know what is going to compose your strings.

The enum is the types of characters that can be in my string (can see that it's limited). If a character with a smaller value is before a character with a bigger value, like IV, then I subtract the preceding character's value from the one after it. Otherwise you add. The code is my attempt, but I can't get enums to work with my algorithm...

```
std::string s = "III";
int sum = 0;

enum {I = 1, V = 5, X = 10, L = 50, C = 100, D = 500, M = 1000};

// O(n) iteration.
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
  // Must subtract.
  if (s[i] < s[i+1]) {
    sum += s[i+1] - s[i];
  }
  // Add.
  else {
    sum += s[i];
  }
}

std::cout << "sum is: " << sum;
```

My questions then are 1) Is using enum with a string possible? 2) I know it's possible to do with a unordered_map but I think enums is much quicker.

Comment: 3) its much faster with simpler switch/case

Comment: Have you benchmark the performance to claim that...?

Comment: @IlyaBursov You mean using switch statements with enums?

Comment: @user202729 I didn't benchmark this, just going off the for loop, n being string length.

Comment: @JessicaWang implement without enums first, add them later if you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 2) I know it's possible to do with a unordered_map but I think enums
>   is much quicker.

you're comparing oranges with apples.

first, `enum` is not a container. it's basically just like a list of *known* constants.

when you mean the access time of `operator[]`:

for [`unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map):

> Unordered map is an associative container that contains key-value
>   pairs with unique keys. Search, insertion, and removal of elements
>   have **average** *constant-time* complexity.

for `string` it's also *constant time* access.

> 1) Is using enum with a string possible

No. An `enum` key is basically like an "alias" for the value. Note that each string is a sequence of characters:

`V != "V"`

Answer (score 3):

If you won't mind minor memory overhead, you can do something like this:

```
int table[256];
table['I']=1;
table['V']=5;
...
```

and then

```
sum += table[s[i]];
```

and so on. This approach is guaranteed to be `O(1)`, which is basically the fastest solution you able to get. You can also use `std::array` instead of POD array, encapsulate all this in some class and add assertions, but this is the idea.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to convert a `char` or a `string` to an `enum` without some kind of mapping. Because the compiler replaces the `enum` with its underlying value during compilation. So you cannot dynamically access the `enum` with its name stored in a `string`.

You have to use either any one of `map` family or `if else` construct to achieve your need.

Comment: So it boils down to enum only representing integral types and chars and strings are not integral types... So weird question: Would my method have worked if I had passed in an array of enums (like a makeshift "string") to my for loop? Then it's just enum to enum mapping, which is OK.

Comment: @JessicaWang actually, char is integral type. It's value is your problem. `'I'` equals `73` and `'X'` equals `88`, but you want `'I'` to be equal `1` and `'X'` to be equal `10`, that's why mapping is required